# Windows Media Center 8 Video Quality is poor compared to the "Video" Player

Tags: video, windows-8, codec, windows-media-center

I can't figure out why the WMC8 video player has a worse quality than the Video player in Windows 8.  I have tried updating codecs to ffdshow but it doesn't change the quality in WMC.  The image looks more Aliased and boxy whereas in the video player it is smoother.

Has anyone had similar issues or have thoughts on fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shark codecs solved this issue.  The codecs included with Win8 aren't the best.